# Creating products overall score across different data sets

Tags: dataset, propensity-scores, rating

I've created product score mapping that gets ranking for product according to reviews from different websites and in different contextual categories.
There are 3 contextual categories: eCommerce/ Experts/ Social
here is a link to the [Products scoring map](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F1plTQO2XEFzKR9Uu664z8ndLPg2_gE-FimOpIx19Oo/edit?usp=sharing) files
After finalizing the mapping, I came across 3 problems:
1. how do I calculate which of the products should be ranked 1st in website 1 when Product x is rated higher BUT with lower amount of reviews while Product y is with lower rating but from much higher number of reviews 
2. How to calculate overall score per category when Product x has ratings from 2 websites while Product y has ratings from 3 websites
3. Given that all 3 categories are evenly weighted, how to calculated overall score when product 1 & 2 don't have same number of rating per websites